# Django static page not found 404

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Django css file not found error, loading css file failed, getting 404 file not found error *also* **i am getting another error:

> Not allowed to load local resources.

Yes, I've tried *c:/path/chrome.e xe -*, all it does is launch  a browser, doesn't navigate me to any `url/website`.

What you guys suggest, this is my code. I'll be posting only the code which I think is to be relevant. My Django version is the latest one,2.

Browser Chrome

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/care/style.css 404 (Not Found)
```

settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'care.apps.CareConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**style.css** is present inside the directory Care which is present inside another directory called static.

I tried with relative and 'absolute path', when I tried with absolute path, I am getting a different error

> Not allowed to load local resources.

Just to be through, I actually copied the link from HTML source code and paste it in the browser and it does take me to the style.css file.Nothing is wrong with the path.

why Django not detecting css file ? I am facing the same issue in firefox browser too, except it doesn't list the error unlike Chrome

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="{% static  'care/style.css' %}" />
```

Comment: Have you already done everything explained here, including `urls.py`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Greetings Selcuk, Yes, I just now did, still getting the same error, unable to detect the css file. I added this to urls.py"+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)" as you suggested,but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If your `MEDIA_URL` is defined as **/media/**, you can do this by adding the following snippet to your APP urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

1. Set the `STATIC_ROOT` setting to the directory from which you’d like to serve these files, for example:

   STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"

Run the `collectstatic` management command:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will copy all files from your static folders into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory.